# If my server has unmetered 100mbps, how can I check how much my bandwidth is being saturated right now?

Tags: php, linux, bandwidth

I'm designing a PHP application that works on several upload servers
What I basically want to do, is to use a Cronjob that fetches reports from each sub-server, and gives me:
1- How much space is left on the drive and
2- How much the bandwidth for that server is saturated (e.g. if a server is running at full bandwidth, use another now)

The first problem I solved with df on linux, but how do I get the current bandwidth saturation to be used in my PHP app? Which command should I use in linux?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use something like Nagios or Zabbix?

Comment: You can use the iptables byte counters to get a  good idea of how many bytes are going in/out - if you log those counters on a periodic basis you'll able to see how close to 100mbps you're going.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output of [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) while executing a command, but I figure you already do that for `df`.

As for the bandwidth, this is described [here](http://www.madmadmod.com/sysadmin/54-how-to-get-the-current-network-bandwidth-usage-on-linux.html). You could read those files directly in PHP.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is have my php function output something like "54mbps" which means I'm using 54 of the 100mbps available to my server, in that particular moment